# Indiquer l'année à laquelle un établissement a débuté ses opérations

Tags: usage, abréviations

Quelle serait la formulation correcte à utiliser sur une enseigne pour indiquer l'année à laquelle un établissement a débuté ses opérations qui serait un équivalent de "Est. 1991" en anglais?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je dirais *Fondé en 1991* ou bien *Depuis 1991*, comme dans:

- *LU, créateur de biscuits depuis 1846*
- *Paul, maison de qualité fondée en 1899*

Answer (score 2):

J’utiliserais « Fondé en 1991 », en prenant garde à accorder « fondé » en genre et nombre à l’enseigne.

> Maison Duchmole, fondée en 1991
>
> Établissements Beaubidet, fondés en 1991